# Twitter Post iOS6 'Cancel' button issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I'm in the process of changing my app for iOS6 and iPhone use, I can't seem to figure out why when I post from Twitter using the new Social framework I have to press 'Cancel' twice to close, anybody else have this issue or a fix? Here is the code for the button.

```
- (IBAction)twitterPost:(id)sender
{
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController   composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is my tweet, hello!",mySLComposerSheet.serviceType]];
    [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
[mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    NSLog(@"dfsdf");
    switch (result) {
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            break;
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}];


}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the completionHandler before presenting the View Controller?

Comment: That did the job, thanks Alex.

Comment: Nice one, I've posted the comment as an answer (see below). Cheers!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your using the mySLComposerSheet this works great...

```
[mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
[mySLComposerSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: And then you need to remember to NOT do this for a Facebook SLComposeViewController, which auto-dismisses itself! rdar:12440972

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that.

Comment: @Steven, can you check if Apple has fixed this as of today? Quite recently they fixed a lot of rdars...

Comment: I've been trying to verify but no luck so far due to another issue.

Comment: Fixed in a recent SDK release.

Comment: You can't use `mySLComposerSheet` since this is happening inside the block code. use `self` instead of `mySLComposerSheet`. BTW, thanks for the hint :)

Comment: Answering @Klaas, this issue still exists for twitter as of October, 2013 with iOS 7 SDK.

Comment: This is needed both in ResultCancelled and on ResultDone for Twitter but not Facebook

Answer (score 9):

My experience with SLComposeViewController is that twitter and weibo controllers need to be dismissed manually while the facebook controller seems to be better behaved.

If I don't dismissViewControllerAnimated myself, tapping the "Send" button will send the tweet or weibo posting but I'll be left with what seems to be an invisible view over my own view. Thus I can no longer interact with my app.

I don't know why my app is working like this... Interestingly, the completionHandler for cancel gets called just once. The second tap dismisses the view controller.

```
+ (void) shareText:(NSString*)text image:(UIImage*)image social:(NSString*)service url:(NSString*)url
{
    SLComposeViewController*    controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:service];

    [controller setInitialText:text];
    [controller addImage:image];
    [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    controller.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        if( SLComposeViewControllerResultDone == result )
        {
            NSLog(@"rewards for share: %@!", service );
        }
        if( ![SLServiceTypeFacebook isEqualToString:service] )  // facebook behaves
            [[CBLAppDelegate instance].activeViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
    };
    [[CBLAppDelegate instance].activeViewController presentViewController:controller animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Exactly the same. Did you send some bug report to Apple? Or do you have a better way to solve it?

Answer (score 7):

Found the issue. It only happens when a completion handler is added to TWTweetComposeViewController. If added, make sure to call:

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Please use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` instead of `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Answer (score 3):

Try this buddy

```
   [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

        switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                [self performSelector:@selector(showalert)];
                [mySLComposerSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                [self performSelector:@selector(showalert1)];
                [mySLComposerSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                break;

            default:
                break;


        }
    }];
```

Comment: dissmissViewControllerAnimated is required if you use Twitter, but not if you use Facebook - there it works without!

Answer (score 1):

Posting comment above as an answer:

> Have you tried setting the completionHandler before presenting the View Controller?